# Lost Notes and now I do not know what to do with NotesV4.storedata

Tags: notes.app

could someone please help me, as I am so confused -

I just realized I lost my Notes, and then I search for them in Finder - Go, and I found this document "NotesV4.storedata", but I do not know, what to do with it ---

Hope someone could help me! thanks in advance <3

Comment: What OS? Notes is up to V7 in Mojave, can't check Catalina.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have lots of options to recover Notes. 1. Using icloud, 2. Using Time Machine Backup, 3. From the Recently Deleted folder.